# Controller in view doesn't update the view model upon being edited

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following form.

```
@model LoginVm
<form asp-controller="Sec" 
      asp-action="Authorize"
      asp-all-route-data="@Model.Querify" 
      method="post">
  Email:  <input asp-for="@Model.UserName" /> <br />
  Password: <input asp-for="@Model.Password" /><br />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The view model is like this.

```
public class LoginVm
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

  public IDictionary<string, string> Querify 
    => new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      { "username", UserName },
      { "password", Password },
      { "returnurl", ReturnUrl }
    };
  }
```

However, in the receiving method shown below, only the values that are written to the view model **before rendition** are present. So, whatever I put in the view model prior to passing it into the view, it's there. Any changes I try to do to the model in the input boxes are lost.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Authorize(
  [FromQuery]string returnUrl, 
  [FromQuery]string userName, 
  [FromQuery] string password)
{ ... }
```

I though based on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-input-tag-helper) that I bound the value from the input box to the fields in the model but apparently I have not. Not sure how to diagnose it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be binding the original data back due to the line:

```
      asp-all-route-data="@Model.Querify"
```

I think this is sending the original model back to the controller as the parameters and ignores the ones in your form.

Remove that line and replace it with

```
 asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl"
```

Edit:

Updated based on comments.

Tested this as working, looks like the [FromQuery] is also an issue so replaced with just taking the viewmodel back.

Controller code:

```
  public IActionResult Sec()
    {
        var viewModel = new LoginVm();

        viewModel.ReturnUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Sec(LoginVm viewModel)
    {
       return Redirect(viewModel.ReturnUrl);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
     public class LoginVm
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
 @model LoginVm
<form asp-controller="Authorization"
  asp-action="Sec"   
asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl"
  method="post">
Email:  <input asp-for="@Model.UserName" /> <br />
Password: <input asp-for="@Model.Password" /><br />
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: To contextualize what @Mark is saying, when using the `@`-based embedded C# syntax in a Razor page, those values are evaluated at the time the View is generated. Once the markup for the page is created, the Model ceases to exist - it is not able to be effectively mutated as far as your view is concerned.

Comment: I think you're right - the rendition of the query string may occur as the page is loaded and **at that point**, the user name and password aren't set. However, the resolution you're proposing won't do it since I need to pass the actually entered credentials somehow. Suggestions?